# Azure Function, Dependency Injection, "there is no argument given that corresponds to the formal parameter", dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to call a repository class from an Azure function but I am getting an error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the formal parameter

I copied the repository class structure from a .NET Core Web API project and know this has to do with dependency injection.

The constructor of the repository class looks like this:

```
public CaseRepository(ILogger<CaseRepository> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

How can I pass this into the static method of an Azure Function as I do with the Web API call like this:

```
[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, CaseRepository caseRepository)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the dependency declaration in the `Startup` class as shown in [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Startup.cs) file and later instead of defining the function as `static` define it normal class function. In the class constructor inject the required dependency. See [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Triggers/Http/ToDoItemsController.cs) for reference.

Startup class

```
 [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]

 namespace YourNamespace
 {
   public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
   {
      builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICaseRepository, CaseRepository>();
   }
 }
```

Usage - here  `ICaseRepository` is injected in the class containing the Azure functions.

```
public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly ICaseRepository caseRepository;

    public TestFunction(ICaseRepository  caseRepository)
    {
        this.caseRepository= caseRepository;
    }

    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // ... use caseRepository instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am testing this out now and will mark as the answer when complete.

Comment: sure, thanks. let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Sorry. Had to put out a fire. checking now.

Comment: Worked, @user1672994. Thank you. I didn't have an interface so I just used  builder.Services.AddSingleton<CaseRepository>();